# What are these unknown client errors on GAE instance?

Tags: php, django, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed Django Application on GAE.
After that, I'm getting a client error on unknown files.
Those files are below.

[image]

I know only `favicon.ico` because I haven't uploaded it yet. But I don't know others.
Almost of them look about WordPress.
Are these client errors attacks for WordPress files on GAE?
How can I stop these?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, those look like wordpress files. Was your Application successfully deployed? If so, are you able to run it? You said you're getting ```client error``` - does this mean you see these errors from the browser side?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I succeeded to deploy and my application is running. There is the section ```client error``` in GAE console page. I can see 'client errors' in there.

Comment: Those are bots/automated scripts some of which are probably looking for weaknesses to exploit. We get those too (and have always gotten them in our GAE deployed sites). Still haven't figured out a way to block them. Tried using firewall rules but they'll just change their IPs

Comment: Since we were facing the same issue for our website, we built a [solution](https://firewall.nocommandline.com/) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as community wiki:

> Those are bots/automated scripts some of which are probably looking
> for weaknesses to exploit. We get those too (and have always gotten
> them in our GAE deployed sites).